# Batch Script Cycle through a list in a for loop while calling another file

Tags: loops, batch-file, variables

I am trying to call same batch file X times (in this code its 3) while passing a variable that is from a list that I cycle through.  So in this case the list is (I J M) so I wish to call the batch file X times passing I then J then M then I then J then M and so on.

My current code is this:

```
@echo off

set letters=I J M

set /a dl = 0

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (%letters%) do (
  set /a dl+=1
  set ltrs[!dl!]=%%i
)

set /a lCount = 0

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (

   start "RBatch%%x" cmd /k call RBatch.bat !ltrs[!lCount!]!
   set /a lCount+=1
   if !lCount! geq !dl! set /a lCount = 0
   
)

PAUSE
```

The RBatch.bat file is just:

```
echo %1
PAUSE
```

Currently RBatch.bat just displays lCount...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Change `!ltrs[!lCount!]!` to `!ltrs[%%x]!`

Comment: That is going to make it cycle through the file count not the letters though

Comment: It does that because your code is read as two undefined variables either side of a string, i.e. `!ltrs[!`, and `!]!` expand to nothing, then all that is left is the string `lCount`.

Comment: I do not understand why they are undefined in the loop?

Comment: You cannot do double delayed expansion to access an array variable.  If you use my method the variable will be `I` the first time the loop executes. Then `J` on the second iteration and so one.  I am not sure why you have the counter inside the `FOR /L` group because the loop itself is counting for you.

Comment: But this still begs the question why you are not just doing this all with one `FOR` command?  `for %%i in (%letters%) do start "RBatch%%i" cmd /k call RBatch.bat %%i`

Comment: Basically I want to launch X number of windows(14 actually) and cycle through the letters on each launch IE 1-I, 2-J, 3-M, 4-I, 2-J etc